# Unable to install Docker on Ubuntu 17

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am installing Docker by following this [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) tutorial. It doesn't work for me. Is it because I am using Ubuntu 17?

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

the error is

"E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate"

I did all the apt-get update.

looks like can not find docker-ce package. What should I do?

Comment: You probably didn't add their repo to your `apt-sources.d/`.

Comment: yeah, I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909691/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-17-04

Answer (score 5):

I found answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/909691/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-17-04

The following procedure fixed my problem and I can install and run Docker on Ubuntu 17 with no issue:

Docker hasn't setup a repository for the latest ubuntu, but that's an easy fix because their release for ubuntu 16 is compatible. For the time being, just edit /etc/apt/sources.list and on the line:

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
Replace zesty by xenial. Run sudo apt-get update and you can proceed with sudo apt-get install docker-ce

Answer (score 0):

The Docker installation package available in the official Ubuntu repository may not be the latest version. To get the latest and greatest version, install Docker from the official Docker repository. This section shows you how to do just that.

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04